# pdo Member function query error coming

Tags: php, pdo

```
I am getting Call to a member function query() on a non-object in G:\PleskVhosts\angelsoftweb.com\angelunitrax.angelsoftweb.com\header.php on line 116
```

db.php

```
<?php
$servername = "########";
$username = "########";
$password = "########";
$dbh = "rfid";
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbh', $username, 
$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

header.php

```
<?php

foreach($sql=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM header_section") as $st) {
echo'
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
<ul style="margin-top: 13px;">
<li><a href="callus.php"><span style="margin-left:5px; color:white; 
font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"><b>'.$st['call_us_name'].'</b></span>   
<span style="margin-left:5px; color:white; font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;">'.$st['number'].'</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>';
}

?>
```

I tried to solve this but not got what is the problem van some one help me with this to solve this as soon as possible...

Comment: You've already asked the same thing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532794/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object and have had plenty of suggestions. I'd recommend you read Seans advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is variable interpolation in this line

`'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbh'`

Replace single quote `'` with double quote `"`

Your script is taking variables in that line as string.

That line should look like this

`"mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbh"`

Your db.php shoud look like this

```
<?php
$servername = "########";
$username = "########";
$password = "########";
$dbh = "rfid";
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbh", $username, 
$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please specify in the question which line is 116, it would be much easier to answer if we can see the exact operator.

<s>Usually this error happens when the connection object is not created properly.
Try to set error mode to exception and put it in a `try..catch` block.</s>

EDIT: it's not quite clear where does `$conn` come from in `header.php`. The database handler in `db.php` is `$pdo`

Comment: ya by mistake it was $conn not $pdo... and line no 116 means where foreach loop start ...